# Windows 11 context menu: move "rename" to primary context menu

Tags: windows, context-menu

When I right-click a file in Windows 11, in order to get to the "rename" option, I need to go into the additional options. Is there a way to move "rename" to the primary context menu that displays immediately after a right click?

Or maybe it is there and I just don't see it?

Comment: Don't think this is possible without a custom extension. Any reason your not just hitting **F2** instead?

Comment: there should be a rename icon at the top of the context menu. but its only expressed as a hieroglyph. it should look like a rectangle with an I-bar cursor over it. believe me, the context menu is not a good part of the win11 user experience, but you shouldn't need to access additional options just to rename.

Comment: @Mario you taught me a good trick.

Comment: @Frank Thomas maybe you could turn that into an answer. I will modify the question to make it easier for you.

Comment: Also, one click to highlight the thing.. wait 1 sec.. one more click on the text and it will move to rename mode.  The wait only needs to be enough to where windows doesn't think that you are double clicking the thing.

Comment: https://pureinfotech.com/bring-back-classic-context-menu-windows-11/

Comment: F2 is the shortcut to edit/rename in nearly all compliant Windows programs like Excel, Access, 7z, File managers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rename remains on the main context menu, but it has been moved to the top/bottom zone of the menu, and no longer displays text (just a pictogram) unless you hover the mouse over it.

The icon should look like a rectangle with an I-Bar cursor inside.

Ironically, the "Undo Rename" context menu entry which appears after you have renamed an item appears as a standard context menu entry with a small icon and text.

If you do just wish to revert the context menu to the win10 version, there are a number of options involving either registry changes, or tweak applications as @moab indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Rename is now an easily overlooked icon on top of the first context menu in Windows 11. Look again! My feelings of insanity and frustration immediately turned into wowed blushing face. :)